# sonar qube time machine blank lines of code

Tags: sonarqube

Hi I configured sonarqube and triggered maven run for unit test cases.
I am able to get unit test cases success,failure details but rest all details under Time machine page are blank.

Can any one please  help me on this

Comment: log says coverage information was not collected after analysing jacoco.exe

Comment: What version of SonarQube are you using?

Comment: i am using soanr qube 4.3.2

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to independently produce coverage xml and absorb it in sonar. Major changes happened in sonar 4.3 wherein sonar folks removed the support for tools which helps in producing coverage. Please check it out!. Moreover if you find this post useful please like it.